# ADT plug-in fails to install on Eclipse, PowerPC, Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, installation, adt, powerpc

I'm trying to install ADT plug-in in Eclipse 3.5.2 which I got from PowerPC Ubuntu repositories. ADT 16.0.0 or above requires Eclipse 3.6 or higher so I tried 15.0.1 and 9.0.0.
ADT 15.0.1 installation completed 100%, I clicked "Apply Now" and got a bunch of errors. From Error [Log](http://pastebin.com/wZwSETWN):

```
Invalid preference page path: com.android.ide.eclipse.preferences.main
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.intro".
Undefined context while filtering dialog/window contexts
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.environment_1.0.301.v200908101600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_1.1.2.v201001222130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent_1.0.1.R35x_v20100209.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core_1.4.1.v200911141735.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v200902170519.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.jem.util_2.0.201.v201001252130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.1.102.v200910200227.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver_1.1.301.v200805140415.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.edit_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration_1.1.301.v200908101600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v200909240008.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.emf_1.1.301.v200908181930.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/javax.xml_1.3.4.v200902170245.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core_1.1.402.v201001222130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks_1.1.300.v200904160730.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xml.serializer_2.7.1.v200902170519.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.ui_1.1.402.v200901262305.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.2.104.v200911120201.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.1.402.v201001251516.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.core_1.1.201.v200806010600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Invalid preference page path: DDMS
Invalid preference page path: LogCat
```

ADT 9.0.0 Installation went the same. From Error [Log](http://pastebin.com/32TMwWZK):

```
Invalid preference page path: com.android.ide.eclipse.preferences.main
Undefined context while filtering dialog/window contexts
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.environment_1.0.301.v200908101600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_1.1.2.v201001222130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.concurrent_1.0.1.R35x_v20100209.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core_1.4.1.v200911141735.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xml.resolver_1.2.0.v200902170519.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.jem.util_2.0.201.v201001252130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.common_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.1.102.v200910200227.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.uriresolver_1.1.301.v200805140415.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.edit_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.emfworkbench.integration_1.1.301.v200908101600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xerces_2.9.0.v200909240008.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.emf_1.1.301.v200908181930.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/javax.xml_1.3.4.v200902170245.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.gef_3.5.1.v20090910-2020.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core_1.1.402.v201001222130.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks_1.1.300.v200904160730.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi_2.5.0.v200906151043.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.apache.xml.serializer_2.7.1.v200902170519.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.ui_1.1.402.v200901262305.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.validation_1.2.104.v200911120201.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.core_1.1.402.v201001251516.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.wst.common.core_1.1.201.v200806010600.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Unable to access file "plugins/org.eclipse.draw2d_3.5.2.v20091126-1908.jar!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Invalid preference page path: DDMS
Invalid preference page path: LogCat
```

Android tab did not appear in Window > Preferences.
Also, both installations took 2 hours.
So, is it possible to install ADT plug-in to Eclipse on PowerPC Ubuntu? Is there any way to install Eclipse 3.6 or 3.7 on my system? My computer is PowerPC G4, Emac (ATI Graphics), Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, never install Eclipse from a Linux package manager or repository; always download from www.eclipse.org

The PowerPC linux builds are only available for the Eclipse SDK, not the packages listed on the main Eclipse Downloads page. Here's the link for the latest release of Eclipse (3.7.2/Indigo): http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/index.php

The other thing to make sure of is that you have the Oracle JDK and have configured Eclipse to use it, as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). Most Linux distros have gcj on the system path and it doesn't play nice with Eclipse.

From there you should be able to install the ADT according to the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#downloading).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to install [Eclipse SDK 3.6.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.2-201102101200/eclipse-SDK-3.6.2-linux-gtk-ppc.tar.gz) (because 3.7.2 was only available for PPC x64) and the ADT 18 plugin (after pointing Eclipse to use IBM JDK 6). Unfortunately Android emulator didn't work, which was my goal. When launching it from Eclipse AVD Manager I get `emulator: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` when launching through terminal `cannot execute binary file`.

Answer (score 0):

I will throw in here just in case someone runs across my problem

Mint 32 bit, all updates and upgrades applied

sudo apt-get updates

sudo apt-get upgrades)

Eclipsed Indigo Classic - sudo apt-get eclipse

java - sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

Trying to install the Android Eclipse Plugin r18 continually failed with the org.eclipse.wst.sse.core missing error that seems common and random at the same time. Note, this did not happen using 64 bit mint/eclipse etc. go figure. and never on windows.

Here is what I did after trying a lot of different patterns found here on Stack and experimenting using snaps on a virtual box to find the right recipe for me.

1. Fresh eclipse classic indigo install 3.7.0 (sudo apt-get eclipse) as mentioned above
2. Start eclipse from the command (sudo eclipse)
3. Add the repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo in the Help/Install New Software section
4. Install Linux tools from the list of options from step 3
5. After restart try to install the android tools again from the http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ repository ( Success !!! )
6. After restart CLOSE eclipse (don't let it install the sdk etc)
7. Start Eclipse normally and let the tools install the SDK for you, or click on the "Window" menu if it doesnt do this immediately on restart to install the base sdk package
8. Go to the Android SDK manager under the window menu and download any other api's etc you need

This worked for me, many similar things did not, not sure what the differences where etc. and also note I had ZERO issues using 64 bit mint (which is a bit counter intuitive considering the problems the ADB has with 64 bit)

Not THE answer, but certainly an answer for someone having same issues I was (Hopefully)